# How to Find Exact Difference Between two Times(24 hours Format)

Tags: php

```
 $time1      = "24:00" //in hours:minutes
 $time2      = "18:32"// in hours:minutes
             ---------
 $difference = "5:28"
             ----------
```

I need difference look like that.(difference = 5:28) what can I do in php.  The values are **time durations**, not dates and the other post does not answer my question.

I was stuck with that simple calculation.

Comment: already answered but the answer contains date and time. i need time difference

Comment: Is the the difference between two *timestamps* [eg `2015-01-01 24:00` and `2015-01-01 18:32`] or the difference between two *durations* [eg: `24 hours, 0 minutes` and `18 hours, 32 minutes`]?

Comment: I dont need timestamp. only need difference of that 2 values.

Comment: from the dupe `$d1=new DateTime("24:00");
$d2=new DateTime("18:32");
$diff=$d2->diff($d1);
print_r( $diff ) ;`

Comment: Use `explode(':', $time1)`, `$duration1 = $hours1 * 60 + $minutes1`, calculate the difference, do math to convert it to hours and minutes, display.

Comment: @Sammitch, dont, use the proper date\times tools

Comment: @Dagon you can't use DateTime to diff two durations. You will get errors due to timezones, leap days/seconds, and DST.

Comment: you can: http://codepad.viper-7.com/7XmsB4

Comment: @Dagon you can, except for when any of the things I said happen and your results go haywire. DateTime objects represent a *point* in time, not an arbitrary *span* of time.

Comment: so is it easier to add a date to my method, or yours?

Comment: `$dif1 = strtotime($time1)-strtotime($time2);`  
 `$hours = intval( $dif1/(60*60));`  
 `$mins = ($dif1-($hours*3600))/60;` @BalaMurugan

Comment: @Dagon, you should consider lifting the duplicate flag.

Comment: nope, its totally a dupe, and there are a dozen ways to do this, like anything in php

Comment: @Dagon THERE IS NO DATE. This is "24 hours, 0 minutes MINUS 18 hours, 32 minutes", not "the difference between midnight and 6:32PM on a particular day".

Comment: im not sure what we are screaming about? but im going to work

Comment: Thank you Subin Thomas Its working Perfectly. Thank You Very Much

Comment: @Dagon if you're looking at a clock, it's a Date and Time and you can use the `DateTime` object/functions. If you're looking at a Stopwatch it's a duration and treating it as a DateTime [or similar functions like strtotime] can and will introduce errors in the calculation because of DST transitions and leap time adjustments. It will work 99.9% of the time, but it will break *badly* 0.01% of the time.

Comment: @Sammitch : Yes. there is a chance of break. In such case, we need to think of adding base year 1970 in conversion. `strtotime("1970-01-01 ". $time2);` . Duplicate flag was not necessary.

Comment: That's it, I give up.

Comment: use strtotime() for both time and then subtract both you will get the difference of both